# IE: "overflow: scroll" on parent and "margin: 0 auto" on child do not work properly

Tags: html, css, overflow, centering, absolute

I've got the following problem in Internet Explorer 9+ which is really weird. The code produces strange results in these browsers and works fine in Chrome/Safari, Firefox and Opera.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="absolute"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.outer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: #ECD078;
}

.inner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 2000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #D95B43;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #53777A;
}

.absolute {
    width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #53777A;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -110px;
}
```

Outer container has overflow: auto and position: fixed. Inner container has a set width and margin: 0 auto to keep it centered. Everything works fine in all browsers apart from IE (all versions). In IE the inner container does not center properly and moves several pixels to the left.

The example fiddle has an absolute container that is positioned so that it sits next to the inner container to illustrate the problem in IE. When I remove overflow: auto from the outer container it works fine but I need that as the it needs to be scrollable. Any suggestions why that happens and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/g7TpK/2/

Comment: I have just tried your fiddle in Chrome on Windows 7 and the result looks exactly as IE9. Are you by any chance testing on Chrome for OSX?

Answer (score 0):

It think this is happening because of the scrollbars that appear in Windows browsers but don't in OSX browsers. The `.inner` block is centred across the inside width of `.outer`, which is entire window width minus scrollbars. Whereas `.absolute` is centred across the entire window width.

To verify, add the following CSS to your fiddle, which will force a scrollbar to appear in Chrome on OSX:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 11px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

You will get the same result you got in Windows. The `.inner` block is always correctly centred, with scrollbars or without.

An easy way to align your blocks is to move the `.absolute` block within the `.outer` block. This way both `.inner` and `.absolute` are positioned relative to the same parent.

Comment: Oh wow! You're right - this solution works. Unfortunately it is quite limited as it only addresses webkit browsers.. so Firefox on OSX still has the wrong centering. Also how do we know that all scrollbars are 11px? I just found out that the windows 8 one is 16px.. This seems like a dead end.

Comment: @YavorPunchev is the absolutely positioned div in your example just to demonstrate centring, or do you actually want to position an element that way? If the concern is centring `.outer`, then like I said, it's always properly centred.

Comment: Well yeah - in production I've got absolutely positioned elements (similar to the fiddle example) that mess up with the centering of the inner container.. so they are centered with left: 50% and negative margin. Does that mean that they don't get affected by scrollbars at all and always have one position? If so, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Actually, a quick way to fix that is move `.absolute` to be inside `.outer`.

Comment: It works for the absolute element, but there is a fixed element as well and for that one it doesn't..

Comment: Try making that fixed element absolute, and put it inside `.outer`. Otherwise consider posting a different question with sample code so that it's easier to troubleshoot. I believe your original question here has been answered ;)